# Html can't load avi file in parent directory

Tags: html, media-player, avi

In html, this line succesfully loads a local avi I have in my hard disk

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" width="1280" height="720" src="fe.avi" autostart="false"
```

The problem is I want to load the same file, but in the parent directory. So, you say, ../ would work, but it doesn't. Once the file (fe.avi) has been transfered, the current lines make the player appear but the screen stays black:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" width="1280" height="720" src="../fe.avi" autostart="false"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative path works perfectly fine.

I tried  `src="../2.avi"` or `src="../test/1.avi"` - video was found and played (no `base` attribute needed - it's default to '.').

But at first it was only worked in IE9; in Crome & Firefox I got black area where the player supposed to be.

I noticed that Chrome was trying to use VLC Media player plugin instead of Windows Media player plugin.

I found out there is no way to use WMP plugin [with the latest chrome](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/wmp-extension-for-chrome):

> If you are running Windows 7, and your Chrome browser is version 33 or newer, the extension will NOT work

Have no idea what is wrong with Firefox and WMP - on the settings page all the settings maps to the WMP but Firefox also uses VLC plugin.

After updating VLC to the latest version (I had v1.* installed) - Chrome and Firefox play the video using VLC plugin and they fine with relative paths too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use relative path, you need to assign the base property for it. For example your html located in "http://mytestsite.com/test". Your FLV files are located in "http://mytestsite.com/". So that you need to add the base property like this

```
<embed 
    type="application/x-mplayer2" 
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
    name="mediaplayer1" 
    ShowStatusBar="true" 
    width="1280" 
    height="720" 
    autostart="false" 
    base="http://mytestsite.com" 
    src="Sample.flv" />
```

For further information, [**Go through this LINK**](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/relative-urls-referenced-correctly-flash.html)

Comment: Can a "base" value point to a local folder such as c:\test\Reference? The html is the Reference folder, while the avi is in test folder. Writing base = "c:\test\Reference" can't point the file correctly. I also can't understand why you've used the src tag two times. So, still no results.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving it an absolute path worked for me.

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" width="1280" height="720" src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\testvideo.mp4" autostart="false">
```

You can also do it like this:

```
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
name="mediaplayer1" ShowStatusBar="true" width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.yoursite.com/downloads/20131205_104200.mp4" autostart="false">
```